# What is difference between connector and extractor in import.io? When to use each of them?

Tags: import.io

When the Connector and and extractor of import.io tool are used? Are they same or there is any differnce?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Extractor**

- you can create an Api for one Type of page or more
- you can use Bulk Extract with an Extractor
- you can use it only with a url of a page

**Connector**

- you can create an Api to extract data from a search results page after performing a search
- you can't use bulk extract for it
- you can only use from a dataset or over the api
- you can use it with a search term not a url

Comment: Basically, an extractor is when you want import.io to simulate user actions on the page before scraping.

Comment: @JignoAlfredVenezuela thats wrong , import.io doesn't work this way at all

Comment: It does simulate a user's actions when doing the search. That's how you "create an api to extract data from a search results page after performing a search"

Comment: simulating user actions means you can do anything and import.io will follow or do the same but thats why connector works only with search's cause it can't just simulate an on click or js interactions for example, plus thats for the connector / my reason when i said its wrong cause for the first time alot of users think that connector can do anything you want but it works strictly in search+results scenario

Comment: My bad. I should have been specific in saying that it simulates a user's search on the website.